Is it safe to call window methods from a different thread?
I am aware that window messages can only be processed in the same thread where this window was created.
But is it possible (or even safe) to create a window and process its messages in one thread and then call something like ShowWindow() from another thread?
Of course we also need to take care of synchronization to prevent race conditions.
And I tried to do this by locking window using std::mutex but got a deadlock.
It seems like a call to ShowWindow() will send a message to that window and block the execution until this message is processed. And because another lock is happening in messages processing the deadlock is inevitable.
My assumption is that while it is technically possible without a mutex, it is unsafe.
So is this true that the only intended way to call ShowWindow() is from the same thread where this window was created?

you of course not need any synchronization here. it senseless. and you can call ShowWindow from other thread. but better use ShowWindowAsync

In general: post a custom message from the background thread to the window so that the GUI thread can action the UI request.

Thread affinity of user interface objects, part 1: Window handles.

for some api this possible and for some api is not.
for example for ShowWindow this is possible. but better in this concrete case use ShowWindowAsync which is special designed for sets the show state of a window of another thread.
from another side DestroyWindow

A thread cannot use DestroyWindow to destroy a window created by a different thread.

so need look for every api separate.

Of course we also need to take care of synchronization to prevent race
conditions

of course not. which race condition ? how ? all window api posts some message(s) to the message queue of the given window thread. so it always proceesed in signle thread
